# How I can change color of the range track without using javascript only pure css?

Tags: css, range, css-transitions

Please advise on this, I am not able to find any info which can help me to change the left side color (red) of the track.

It will be good if its in a pure CSS.

Like below image.

https://codepen.io/MadanSinha/pen/ExobgXe?editors=1010

[image]

Below is my code, please check and advise -

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap');

:root{
  --font: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
   

html, body{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  height:100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 0deg, hsl(6, 100%, 80%), hsl(335, 100%, 65%));
}

.range{
  width:25em;
  height:6em;
  background-color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:3.5rem;
  border-radius:24px;
  box-shadow:20px 20px 60px #bf6363;
}

.data{
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}

.range .field input{
  width:80%;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  height:10px;
  background:#ddd;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
}

.range .field input::-webkit-slider-thumb{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  background:   #ffa399;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #fe6d73;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input{
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #82CFD0 0%, #82CFD0 50%, #fff 50%, #fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="range">
  <p class="data"> You've used <strong> 815 GB </strong> of your storage. </p>
    
  <form class="field">
    <label class="left value">0</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="1000" steps="1" >
    <label class="right value">1000</label>
  </form>
  
</section>
```

Comment: Did you see the warning when you've posted the qustion? **Links to codepen.io must be accompanied by code.**

Comment: Hi 0stone0, here it is pls advise on this https://codepen.io/MadanSinha/pen/ExobgXe?editors=1010

Comment: "*I am not able to find any info which can help me to change the left side color (red) of the track*" - in what way do you want it to be "changed"?

Comment: Hi, I want to change left side color like this image ["https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLTUk.png"]

Answer (score 0):

```
    /* in Chrome*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    input[type='range'] {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 80px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-color: #9a905d;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
      height: 10px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      color: #13bba4;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
    
    input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      width: 10px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      height: 10px;
      cursor: ew-resize;
      background: #434343;
      box-shadow: -80px 0 0 80px #43e5f7;
    }

}
/** FF*/
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: #43e5f7; 
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {  
  background-color: #9a905d;
}
/* IE*/
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: #43e5f7; 
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {  
  background-color: #9a905d;
}
```

you can change colors value! and make your own

Comment: Please post some explanation of the code snippet and why it works. It makes it easier for the reader. See [Reviewing Low Quality Posts - Answers without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation).

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by adding an inset [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) CSS property on the `input[type="range"]` element.

**syntax:**

```css
box-shadow: inset 0px 0 color; /* inset | offset-x | offset-y | color */
```

The **offset-x** value will be used to "fill the track" with the specified color:

- minimum value is 0
- maximum value is the width of the `input[type="range"]`

If you use a negative value instead of *filling from the left* the track will be *filled from the right*.

To reflect the changes you need to update that **offset-x** value from JavaScript based on the actual value of the input, that may require some correction based on its range (min, max, range) and the width of the element.

Below is an example on how you can modify the [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) CSS property from JavaScript:

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');
inputElement.style.boxShadow = `inset ${new_value}px 0 color`;
```

Additionnaly there is this [codepen](https://codepen.io/darkosphere/pen/NWBzdJg) that show an example of that implementation.